# Angular $broadcast only populating data on page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass data from a controller to a directive using `$broadcast` and `$on`.

Data only appears on the directive's HTML template when I refresh the page. It does not appear when I `route` to the controller template with the embedded directive.

The weird thing is, the data appears to have been received when I console log. I have tried using `$timeout` and `angular.element(document).ready`

Controller:

```
$http.getDashboardData(...).success(function(res) { 
      populateResults(res);
      ...
}

function populateResults (data) {
    $rootScope.safeApply(function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('show-results', data);
    });
}
```

Directive:

```
.directive('results',['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: '/html/directives/results.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
        ...

$rootScope.$on('show-results', function(event, args) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        scope.init(args);
    });
});

scope.init = function (args) {

    console.log('ARGS', args); //Has data

    scope.questions = args;
};
```

Controller Page with embedded `results` directive:

```
<div class="myPage">
    <results></results>
</div>
```

Directive HTML:

```
<div>
    QUESTIONS: {{questions}} : //Empty array
</div>
```

**Console Log:** You can see it has data:

[image]

---

Routing sequence:

```
   .config:
        ...
        state('dashboard', {
            url : '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: '/html/pages/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
            resolve : {
                ProfileLoaded : function ($rootScope) {
                    return $rootScope.loadProfile();
                }
            }
        });
```

.run: This is to load profile if user refreshes the page:

```
    $rootScope.loadProfile = function () {
        return Me.getProfile({user_id : Cookies.get('user_id')}).success(function (res) {
            $rootScope.me = res;
        }).error(function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        });
    };
```

Comment: keep in  mind controller runs before template gets digested. Sounds like event could be happening before the directive has been digested. Might be better to use service to share the data or pass the data to directive scope through an attribute

Comment: true, but $broadcast should run in next digest cycle anyway if I remember correctly

Comment: also curious what sequence is regarding "route to controller" and the event occurence

Comment: @charlietfl I'll post the routing

Comment: the application flow is more important than the routing config itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your directive link function, try to use scope.$on instead of $rootScope.$on, and use scope.init directly without document.ready

Comment: If I use `scope` instead of `$rootScope`, `$on` does not receive the broadcast

Comment: That most probably means that it's broadcasted before your directive is displayed. Check your event flow.